# QGIS 2.16.0 crash problem?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I installed QGIS 2.16.0, and for a while everything was ok. When I uninstalled some plugins, appeared to me the window, minidump.

I installed qgis 2.16.2. the problem still exists. when I install and uninstall any plugin I'm getting message box, dump, and QGIS close down. Where is the problem?

[image]

[image]

---

I still have the same problem with the dump file. For all versions of QGIS (14; 16; 18) again the same problem. This is happening on three different computers.

What is the problem?

This dump file has a few megabytes (33MB) and quickly consumes the memory. After a while I have to manually look for these files to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed QGIS LTR 2.14.4.

Consider uninstalling your version and installing the current LTR version which is 2.14.6-Essen. I don't face the minidump issue when closing anymore with this version.

Comment: That should be 2.14.6 ;)

Comment: I have installed and QGIS 2.14.1. essen, but I have no problems with plugins. When I close QGIS 2.14.1 I was getting the same message box minidump, but I did not have problem with that. Now , the problem is bigger, after installing plugins,  my QGIS crash and project not saved.

Comment: I have had the same issue in 2.16.2 (Windows) which corrupted 2.14.2 (Windows) after I uninstalled 2.16.2, even after deleting /.qgis folder. I have reverted to 2.12.2 in Windows and deleted all legacy instances of QGIS -- I can open files created in 2.16.1 (Linux) on the Windows version. To my inexperienced eye it seemed to be a plugin issue.